# unexpected token ( for javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, token

I want to write an algorithm into javascript and I am sure I wrote true . the algorithm gives a number from user and gives the user the result : 1+3+5+...+(2n+1) and "n" is var.
the javascript gives me errors : calc() is not defined , unexpected token;

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Algorithm</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calc(){
            var n = document.getElementById('value').value;
            var sum = 0, i = 1, k = 0;
            for(k=0,k<n,k++){
            sum = sum += i;
            i+=2;
            k++;
            }
            document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = sum;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="value" placeholder="Enter your number"/>
    <button onclick="calc()">OK</button><br/>
    <h1 id="answer"></h1>
</body>
```

Comment: This line `sum = sum += i;` looks dodgy

Comment: In the `for` loop header, you should use `;` instead of `,`: `for(k=0;k<n;k++){`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [for loop causing "Unexpected token" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450168/for-loop-causing-unexpected-token-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `for` loop syntax. You need to use a semi-colon `;` to separate the statements:

```
for( k = 0; k < n; k++ ){
 ...
}
```

Taken from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

> Creates a loop that consists of three optional expressions, enclosed in parentheses and **separated by semicolons**, followed by a statement executed in the loop.

---

The JavaScript engine can not parse your for loop and then it encounters the closing bracket of the loop (which it wasn't expecting as it was still trying to parse the conditions of the loop).

Answer (score 2):

The for() statement needs semicolons (`;`) instead of commas (`,`).

```
for (var k=0; k < n; k++) {
```

The "jshint" tool can be very helpful in catching mistakes in javascript. There's a web version of it on [jshint.com](http://www.jshint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

`for(k=0,k<n,k++){`

You're using commas instead of semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you should have `;` instead of `,` in `for` syntax.

```
for(k=0;k<n;k++){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` statement is using `commas` instead of `semi-colons`.
Change it to use `;`.

```
for(k=0,k<n,k++){
    sum = sum += i;
    i+=2;
    k++;
}
```